# Javascript scrollIntoView(); not loading

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

hi i am making a website for me and i wanted to use the javascript scrollIntoView(); function. the function does work in the console on my site but not in the text where i am currently working in below is the function and the corresponding code.

```
    <script>
        let aboutus = document.querySelector("#aboutus");
        let contact = document.querySelector("#contact");
        let gotoAboutUs = document.querySelector("#gotoAboutUs");

        function navigateAboutUs(e) {
            aboutus.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
        }

        gotoAboutUs.addEventListener("click", navigateSimran, false);
    </script>

this is where i want to go
        <div class="p-5 Simran" id="aboutus">
            <div class="row flex-wrap px-5">
                <div class="card-header ml-5">
                    <img src="images/test.jpg" alt="" style="max-height: 400px; max-width: 400px;">
                </div>
                <div class="card-block px-2 mx-3">
                    <h3 class="card-title"><strong></strong></h3>
                    <p class="card-text"><h5><br></h5></p>
                </div>
                <div class="w-100"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

and this is the button

<a class="nav-link navButton mavenPro" href="#" id="gotoAboutUs"><h3>Wie zijn wij</h3></a>

the button does nothing currently.

thanks for your time
```

Comment: `navigateSimran` is not defined actually

Comment: yea i know changed it still doesnt work it doesnt call the whole function

Answer (score 0):

#### Linking to ids will scroll the element into view.

Add some css:

```css
body {
   scroll-behaviour: smooth;
}
```

Then link the id:

```html
<a href="#aboutus">Go to about us</a>
```

Comment: yea tried that already man it works but it jumps and i would like a smooth scroll